# Webservice is running but Jquery success function does not work

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services

When I clicking on image my asmx webservice is debugging but my jquery success function does not work .

here is my jquery function

```
if (e.key === 'toes') {
            debugger;
            $.ajax({

                url: "SympsService.asmx/GetSymptoms",
                data:{ organ_name: "toes" },
                method: "post",
                dataType: "json",                    
                success: function (data) {
                    debugger;
                    alert("ok");
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            })
        }
```

here is my asmx webservice code

```
 [WebMethod]
    public string GetSymptoms(string organ_name)
    {

        List<symps> listSymptoms = new List<symps>();

        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EhealthConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sendSymptoms", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter();
            parameter.ParameterName = "@organ";
            parameter.Value = organ_name;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);

            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                symps symp = new symps();
                symp.Sympt = rdr["SymptomsName"].ToString();
                listSymptoms.Add(symp);

            }
            string serializedList = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listSymptoms);
            return serializedList;


            //JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            //Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(listSymptoms));

        }



    }
```

I cannot understand what's the problem in my code . plz help me .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any error in console ?

Comment: When you debug the asmx, what's the value of `serializedList`?  "doesn't work" is too vague - does it get called but not have any data?  Does `error:` get called?

Comment: Does your production code have the same missing close bracket typo as the example here?

Comment: You say the `success` method isn't working, then the `error` must be hit in the JS code. That gives you several properties with information about the response you can use to debug the problem. As it stands now you haven't told us enough about the issue to help you

Comment: my consol error is<br/>
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined buttons.print.min.js:1
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/css/buttons.datatables.min.css
Object {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
 newjs.js:220

Comment: My srializedList is "[{\"Sympt\":\"Black Skin\"}]"